# Arch: how to disable auto-login on tty?

Tags: arch-linux, autologin

On my Arch, root can directly login via tty without password. However, for normal users, password is mandatory.

So, How to disable the auto-login of root on tty.

Comment: You are confusing answerers by talking about *automatic login* when you seem rather to have a *passwordless superuser account* or something like the setup in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184486/ .  Explain in your question what prompts you see and have to respond to.  Do you see a `login:` prompt and have to explicitly answer `root`?  Do you see a `password:` prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@ttyN.service?

The context looks like this:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I 38400 linux
```

You just need to delete or disable this service.

Comment: It would normally have been a good idea to validate details through comments (I know you can't comment yet) but your answer seems like a likely possibility which could help others as well.  It might be a tad better if you provided the command to disable the service.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I am a newbee and I will pay attention to it later.

Comment: Disabling the login service entirely is not what the questioner asked for *at all*.

Comment: this kinda works, bit disabling is a bad idea because after reboot, you wont even be able to reach the tty again, requiring usb live boot tools.